# $GOPATH/src/... and vendor/... versions are different

Tags: go, versioning, vendor

My project, using Go 1.8, has a dependency on `github.com/stretchr/testify`. I retrieved the latest using `go get -u github.com/stretchr/testify` and the version in `$GOPATH/src` appears to be correct.

I added the latest version number as a contraint in `Gopkg.toml`:

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/stretchr/testify"
  version = "1.1.4"
```

I then ran `dep ensure -update` and then `dep status` to update the `vendor` directory (output of `dep status`):

```
github.com/stretchr/testify  ^1.1.4  v1.1.4  69483b4  69483b4  1
```

The version in `$GOPATH/src` contains, in the file `github.com/stretchr/testify/assert/assertions.go`, the function `PanicsWithValue`:

```
func Panics(t TestingT, f PanicTestFunc, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) bool {
    // ...
}

func PanicsWithValue(t TestingT, expected interface{}, f PanicTestFunc, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) bool {
    // ...
}

func NotPanics(t TestingT, f PanicTestFunc, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) bool {
    // ...
}
```

but in the version in `vendor`, that function is missing:

```
func Panics(t TestingT, f PanicTestFunc, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) bool {
    // ...
}

func NotPanics(t TestingT, f PanicTestFunc, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) bool {
    // ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I would like to use the function `PanicsWithValue` in my testing. I even tried deleting the entire `vendor` directory and rebuilding it.

Comment: Nothing. v1.1.4 (the latest tag) is from last September. PanicsWithValue was added June 1.

Comment: Is there any way to force `dep` to use the version that is in `$GOPATH/src`?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with `dep` but it looks like it's all-or-nothing. You can remove the constraint entirely though (`version = "*"`) and it should use master@HEAD.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Converted to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pinning the version to v1.1.4, you're specifically telling `dep` to use a version that does not include the feature you want (check the history of the testify package on GitHub - v1.1.4 is from last September, `PanicsWithValue` was added this past June). If you unpin the version (`version = "*"`) it should use master@HEAD which includes `PanicsWithValue`.

Comment: The version in `vendor` still does not contain the `PanicsWithValue` function, after `dep ensure -update; dep prune; dep status`.

Comment: Did you run `dep ensure` after updating the `Gopkg.toml` file?

Comment: What is your `dep status` output for `testify`?

Comment: `github.com/stretchr/testify  *  v1.1.4  69483b4  69483b4  1`

Comment: And my constaint contains: `[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/stretchr/testify"
  version = "*"`

Comment: Looks like you can try removing it from `vendor` and adding it to [`ignored`](https://github.com/golang/dep/blob/master/docs/Gopkg.toml.md#ignored) in your `Gopkg.toml`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that defeats vendoring. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: Then why did you ask "Is there any way to force dep to use the version that is in $GOPATH/src?"? That is the definition of defeating vendoring.

Comment: Sorry. I misspoke. I should have said: "Is there any way to force `dep` to copy the version that is in `$GOPATH/src` to `vendor`?"

Comment: No. `dep` gets dependencies from the canonical source, not from local disk. If you want it vendored, you'll have to modify `Gopkg.toml` to get it to use the canonical version you want. You could try replacing `version = "*"` with `branch = "master"`.